# Extract source data from pivot table in python

Tags: python, pivot-table

I have received an excel file with only pivot table. How can I extract the source data while reading the data in python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: found a solution?